# Control a robot with REST API with JS and Mongodb

Tags: mysql, rest, raspberry-pi, robotics

I tried to write a control connection between my robot and PC or Android. 
Ok. So right now it looks like so:
There is an local apache2 server on my raspberry pi and my robot checks every time my MySQL database which is not efficient especially because MySQL is slow

I need a new solution to improve speed of communication beetween my robot and PC or Android app.

Is it efficient if I setup REST server on my raspberry pi with MongoDB in JS? MongoDB should be much faster than my current MySQL solution. And If I had REST service I can use it to communicate android app or webapp or my pc to my robot.

Could you give me any tip if that helps with my case? Or the current solution client-server with MySQL will give me the same effect. Or there is any other better solution to ensure control connection between raspberry pi robot and different clients.

Comment: what is the bit rate of your connection?

Comment: I havent measured it. The robot works fine. I mean if I press a button it reacts without delay. The problem is that I need always truncate my database if I have too many entries. I save all of them and robot executes only the last command in my MySQL database

Comment: Let's see that "slow" query.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; maybe you are missing a composite index?

Comment: As you know, you'll have additional network latency with the API. I have used a little chip called a "Spark Core" that is api based and it was pretty snappy most of the time, but I doubt that is nearly fast enough for a "realtime" app like robotics.

Comment: Is the webserver necessary? What about  querying the database directly from the controller? Is there a way to do that?